# Easy way to configure QML combobox with 1-25

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have a need for a simple drop-down box containing the numbers 1 through 25 inclusive.

If I set the model up as a simple `25`, I get the values `0` through `24` inclusive. I know I can have a more complicated list model but it seems rather silly to construct a massive array of values when they should be able to be calculated on the fly.

From what I read, it should be a simple matter to create a delegate for setting the display values but, with the QML:

```
ComboBox {
    width: 100
    model: 25
    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        text: index + 1
    }
}
```

the *values* in the drop-down selection area are correct but the value displayed on selection are still zero-based.

How do I get both the selection area *and* the value to be the values `1..25`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `displayText: currentIndex + 1` for the combo box:

```
ComboBox {
    width: 100
    model: 25
    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        text: index + 1
    }
    displayText: currentIndex + 1
}
```