# How to have a numerical model start at 1 in a combobox from QML

Tags: qt, combobox, qml

In the `combobox` from qml we can give them a model with a numerical value.

The options of the `combobox` then start from 0 to the model value minus 1.

What i want is to show the values on the `combobox` plus 1.
But still, if i try to access, with `qml javascript`, the value that is selected in that `combobox` is the original value, what i mean is, if it's the first option it's the value 0. The numbers shall only start from 1 in the display part of `combobox`.

I'm going to give an example (with a model=32):

display of the `combobox`

[image]

the options:

[image]

what i want is them to start at one, like this:

[image]

The code used was the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    height: 200
    width: 400
    Item {
        id: page
        anchors.fill: parent
        width:parent.width
        height: parent.height
        Column{
            width:parent.width
            spacing:10
            ComboBox {
                id:comboBox
                model: 32
                objectName: "test"
                implicitHeight: 30
                displayText: currentText
//                delegate:
//                      Button {
//                          id:buttonCombo
//                          width: parent.width
//                          text:  index+1
//                          height:40
//                          contentItem: Text {
//                              text: buttonCombo.text
//                              font: comboBoxCustom.font
//                              leftPadding: 5
//                              horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
//                              verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
//                              elide: Text.ElideRight
//                          }
//                          background: Rectangle {
//                              color: buttonCombo.hovered ? (buttonCombo.pressed ? "#d8d8d8" : "#e8e8e8" ) : "#fff"
//                          }
//                      }
                anchors.topMargin: 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe this could be done:
`displayText: Number(currentText)+1`
but i don't know if its the best solution...

Comment: My bad: I misread the question - reopening.

Comment: OK, so you still need to redefine the delegate, which means this is still a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46424298/easy-way-to-configure-qml-combobox-with-1-25.

Comment: Why don't you give the combobox a *real* model? The ability in QtQuick APIs to pass numbers as models is just for prototyping reasons (or close to that).

Comment: displayText: Number(currentText)+1 is the best solution